# send different value in jquery with hyperlink

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

i am working on a marketing project.there are some category like bank ,school and many other and i have the same table in my sql database..now i am wanted to show the result of which category user click ..
    my index.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db = mysql_select_db('market', $connection);
?>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var temp = $('a').attr('myval');
        $.post('fetch.php', {
            id: temp
        }, function (data) {
            $('#display').html(data);
            var temp = null;
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:return(0)" myval="school">
                <h3>school</h3>
            </a>
        </li>;
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:return(0)" myval="bank">
                <h3>Bank</h3>
            </a>
        </li>;
        <!--many more......-->
    </ul>
    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
```

and its my fetch.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db         = mysql_select_db('market', $connection);
$x          = $_POST['id'];
$safex      = mysql_real_escape_string($x);

$query = mysql_query("select * from $safex", $connection);

$result = "";

$result .= "<div id='display'>";
$result .= "<table border=\"1\">";
$result .= "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Password(encrypted)</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $result .= "<tr><td> {$row['id']}</td>" . "<td> {$row['name']}</td></tr></p>";
}
$result .= "</table>";

$result .= "</div>";

echo $result;

?>
```

and now my prblem is when i click on any link..its always show tie school data..but i want to show diffent table data on diffenent click..all fields name of all tables are same..
plz help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` to get the attribute of clicked element.

```
var temp = $(this).attr('myval');
```

`$(this)` indicates on which the event was fired. Also as you are using anchor node, so, also use `e.preventDefault()` and also pass `e` argument in event handler function.

Comment: ya..its working..thanks for help..i have done a small mistake..i forget to remove the '' from this...

Comment: @omnath `this` is already defined in javascript and is also a reserved word. So, it does not need quotes around it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, modified the following

```
var temp = $('a').attr('myval');
```

to

```
var temp = $(this).attr('myval');
```